# Function is not being called back to login user

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm attempting to make a login System but seem like it doesn't call back a previous function with a "prepared-statement", and can't continue to login.
The problem I am having is that the login page is returning the error message, that says that “the username doesn't exists”(the The uid exists function seems to not work either way, because if it’s true it only returns “array ” and if false it doesn’t echo out anything ). However the user has an account on the database. I tried logging with both usernames and email (the same result).

Here are the two functions that I'm working within the functions.php file:

```
<?php

function uidExists($conn, $username, $email)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? OR user_email = ?;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("location: ../../pages/register.php?error=stmtfaild");
        exit();
    }

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $email);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $resultData = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultData)) {
        return $row;
    } else {
        $result = false;
        return $result;
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

function loginUser($conn, $username, $pwd)
{
    $userNameExists = uidExists($conn, $username, $username);

    if ($userNameExists === false) {
        header("location: ../../pages/login.php?login=Usernamenotexists");
        exit();
    }

    $pwdHashed = $userNameExists["user_password"];
    $checkPwd = password_verify($pwd, $pwdHashed);

    if ($checkPwd === false) {
        header("location: ../../pages/login.php?login=incorrectpassword");
        exit();
    } elseif ($checkPwd === true) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["userid"] = $userNameExists["id"];
        $_SESSION["username"] = $userNameExists["username"];
        header("location: ../../pages/index.php");
        exit();
    }
}
```

I'm also including the login.php file here:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['login-btn'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username']; //protect aganst hacker
    $pwd = $_POST['password']; //protect aganst hacker using MYSQLi long way

    require_once "connection.php";
    require_once "functions.php";

    if (emptyFieldLogin($username, $pwd) !== false) {
        header("location: ../../pages/login.php?login=empty");
        exit();
    }
    loginUser($conn, $username, $pwd);
} else {
    header("location: ../../pages/login.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: It is not clear which part of your code is not working correctly. Are you saying `uidExists` is returning false?

Comment: `mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);` will never be executed

Comment: In your SQL statement ... OR user_email = ?;" you need to remove semicolon after question mark

Comment: @Stefino76 "Need" is a strong word. Removing the semicolon won't change anything.

Comment: This question looks awfully similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68339023/create-a-log-in-system-by-php-using-functions#comment120778800_68339023

Comment: Of course, when you echo `false` it will print an empty string, and when you echo an array it will print "array". That's how echo works.